# (OwlCarousel) Точки скрыты

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Проблема заключается в том, что на сайте почему-то точки под слайдом не работают, хотя в коде они активированы. Самое интересное, что точки на странице существуют, но подписаны под классом `owl-dots disabled` и визуально скрыты. Я пробовал поставить свойства `display: block` или `padding: 10px`, но ничего не даёт эффекта.

[image: Проблема на гифке]

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="special__list owl-carousel" id="owl_about_main_slider">
    <img class="special__item" src="img/special1.jpg">
    <img class="special__item" src="img/special2.jpg">
    <img class="special__item" src="img/special3.jpg">
    <img class="special__item" src="img/special4.jpg">
</div>
```

---

```
// JavaScript
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() <= 1300){
      startCarousel()
    } else {
      stopCarousel()
    }
})

function startCarousel(){
    $("#owl_about_main_slider").owlCarousel({
        slideSpeed: 300,
        dots: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        items: 4,
        margin: 10
    })
}

function stopCarousel() {
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel')
  owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel')
  owl.addClass('off')
}
```

Нужно ли добавить какие-то необходимые свойства в CSS или ошибка заключается конкретно в `.js` файле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается этому блоку только лишь не хватало класса, под названием `owl-theme`. Точки отображаюся.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте так сначала вы поменяете значение `items: 4` на меньше чем у вас есть блоков img ну что-то типо `items: 3, 2, 1`)) так как dots не отображаються из-за этого скорее всего :)

А если хотите хакнуть disable то поставте `display: block!important`

Comment: Звучит вполне логично, но я поменял на значение ниже и ничего не изменилось. Я когда открывал консоль при значении 4, тогда там были две точки. Кажется разрабы этой библиотеки всё предусмотрели. Да и хакнуть тоже не вышло)

Comment: Не, попутал. Отобразились только кнопки навигации, которые я не ставил.

Comment: Надо было прекрипить вам свой html и js, у меня все работало:)
Ну я думаю я вам дал толчок для размыления как нужно делать.

На счет хака нужно проинспектировать елемент через F12 посмотреть как именно записан класс и запасить в своем CSS его также только уже со своими параметрами и словом important @Endivine Вижу сверху вы уже сами разобрались чего не хватало но думаю даже при том что у вас будет записан owl-theme точки не будут отображаться при равном количестве елементов с параметром items. А так однозначно лайк разобраться самому всегда приятнее чем спросить^^

Comment: Да, но всё равно спасибо, что откликаетесь и помогаете. Такие люди как вы высоко ценятся на этом сайте. = )